# ERROR: La cláusula Handles requiere una variable WithEvents definida en el tipo contenedor o en uno de sus tipos base

Tags: sql, vb.net, .net

El caso es este:

Tengo una ventana de "Menú" en el cual hay un botón que abre otra ventana donde he insertado un DataGrid que tengo de una Base de Datos en SQL Server.

Para agregar la Base de Datos al VB.NET, sólo hice la conexión, agarré y solté el DataGrid desde el listado de tablas de la Base de Datos que me sale en "Orígenes de Datos".

El problema es que si agrego el DataGrid, me da ese error. He intentando hacerlo directo desde un DataGrid vacío y llamar a la tabla desde dentro de la configuración del DataGRid y sigue dándome el mismo error.

Ya he borrado y creado todo mi Proyecto 2 veces y sigue igual.

Al buscar el error en el código, me dice que está en:

> MyBaseBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click

**Que se encuentra en esta pedazo de cógido:**

```
Private Sub CuidadoresBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBaseBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click, MyBaseBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click, MyBaseBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click, MyBaseBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.CuidadoresBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ZooDataSet)

    End Sub
```

**NOVEDAD:**

Si sólo tengo una ventana con DataGrid, todo funciona perfecto. Si agrego otra ventana con otro DataGrid de otra Tabla de la misma Base de Datos, me da el mismo error.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]!. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y asi ganes tu primera medalla. Tambien es bueno leer [ask] para aprender que preguntas son aceptables y como realizar una buena pregunta. En el caso de tu pregunta, sin ver el código que provoca el error no podremos ayudarte correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

No encuentra el nombre del binding

```
Private Sub CuidadoresBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)handles 
CuidadoresBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.CuidadoresBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ZooDataSet)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ponlo así:

```
 Private Sub CuidadoresBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.CuidadoresBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ZooDataSet)
End Sub
```